# how to use SwipeRefreshLayout with Fragments

Tags: android, fragment, swiperefreshlayout

So i was using SwipeRefreshLayout and Fragments for a simple app that i am working on and i have three files:
1.app_bar_main.xml which contains a FrameLayout which is a container for the fragments heres the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.surafel.tryingfragment.MainActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        >

    </FrameLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

2.fragment_main.xml which contains components of the main fragment and a SwipeRefreshLayout heres the code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/refreshMainContent"
    tools:context="com.example.surafel.tryingfragment.MainFragment">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MAIN"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:id="@+id/buttonmain"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

3.MainFragment.java this is the java code for the fragment_main.xml heres the code

```
//i have imported all the necessary classes
public class MainFragment extends Fragment  implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeView;

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,false);
        swipeView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.refreshMainContent);
        swipeView.setColorSchemeColors(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark),getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark),getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light),getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark));

    swipeView.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    public void onRefresh() {
    Log.d("Refreshing","The refresh is working");
    }

}
```

4.i also have `MainActivity.java` file which contains all the necessary codes

the problem is its not changing the color of the `swipeView` and its not even calling the `onRefresh()` method. when i run the
app and swipe down the refresher comes but its color is black and its not executing the `onRefresh()` method.
and also there are no compiletime and runtime errors.
So can anyone please help me,i posted all the code because i thought it could be usefull,Thanks.

Comment: For the colors, I think it's just that you do too much work, you can just pass the resources directly:
    swipeRefreshContainer.setColorSchemeResources( R.color.colorAccent, R.color.otherColor, ...);
For the fucntionality, I'll try to recreate your problem, because I don't spot it yet.

Comment: ok thanks i will be waiting for your answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have called the code  *inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);* twice.

Try returning the object **layout** instead of *inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)*

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, you have to post it in the comments section.